# Marriage and dependent visa application after divorce in Hong Kong

Tags: marriage, dependent-visa, application-status, hong-kong, divorce

I have a few questions in regards to the dependent visa application. Hoped you could help with.

I have been separated with my spouse for over 2 years now. And I'm with my new partner for the last 6 months. Currently, I'm going through the divorce paperwork.

Once it's finalised, and I'm married to my new partner, can I apply for the dependant visa for the partner right away? We're gonna get married in Hong Kong and they're not a HK citizen.

And can I marry right after divorcing?

How do I need to update my marital status (divorce) and how long does it take to process?

Is there any possible issue with that?

And what's the application process and timelines?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you applying to?

Comment: Hi! If I understood correctly. I will be applying for a dependent visa in HK for my partner once I get the divorce papers done with my current spouse and after we get married with my new partner in HK. I have a work visa here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide [a certified copy of the court decision](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/faq/marriage-registration.html#marriage_reg_q2). There's no mention of timeframe between divorce and remarriage. The divorce needs to be final, that's it.

You must file a Notice of Intended Marriage 15 days at least before the wedding.

It's pretty simple, really.

Note that getting married to a Hong Kong resident doesn't give you automatic right of residence. You have to apply, and be accepted. It is usually straightforward, but definitely not a rubber stamp. I know a couple who had to attend something like 8 interviews before the wife received her dependant visa.